# How to reffer in CSS to an input which has class attached to?

Tags: css, button, input, css-selectors

I have the following problem: I have an form with a few inputs. At the end of the form I have a submit and a reset button, which are inputs. I have a style in my CSS file for inputs (white background), but I want to write another style for inputs which are buttons (type=submit and type=reset).

I have tried to make a style named .button, and adding it to the input ( `<input class=button`) but the properties from the input style are used, not the properties from the .button style.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to add more details. Especially the exact CSS and HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look on [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) from CSS2.1 specification:

`[attribute-name=value]` - this selector will match every element with `attribute-name` set on `value` value. So all you need is `input[type=submit], input[type=reset]` selector.

Comment: thank you. can you tell me what browsers do support these settings? Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer (so +1). However note that attribute selectors do not work in IE6. Hopefully you don't need to support IE6, but if you do then you'll need to use classes instead. All other current browsers support it (even IE7 and IE8). See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html for more info.